# How to send transactional email programatically?

Tags: magento-1, email, transactional-mail

This is my code:

```
 $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('newsletter_subscription_confirm_email_template');
            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeId));
            $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeId));
            try {
                $emailTemplate->send($email, $order->getData('customer_firstname')." ".$order->getData('customer_lastname'), array());
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('customer')->__('An email was sent with a confirmation url'));
                $this->redirectSubscribeSuccess();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
```

I received the the email with the content of the transactional email, except that the

`{{var subscriber.getConfirmationLink()}}`
 is empty . **Do you know why ?**

Thanks.!

**[UPDATE]**

```
 $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('newsletter_subscription_confirm_email_template');
            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
            $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
            $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
            if (!$subscriber->getId()
                || $subscriber->getStatus() == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED
                || $subscriber->getStatus() == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                $subscriber->setStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
                $subscriber->setSubscriberEmail($email);
                $subscriber->setSubscriberConfirmCode($subscriber->RandomSequence());
                $subscriber->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                $subscriber->setCustomerId($order->getData('customer_id'));
            }
            try {
                $emailTemplate->send($email, $order->getData('customer_firstname')." ".$order->getData('customer_lastname'), array('subscriber' => $subscriber));
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('customer')->__('An email was sent with a confirmation url'));
                $this->redirectSubscribeSuccess();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Have you set System > configuration > Newsletter > Need to Confirm value to Yes?

Comment: yes :) it is set to `yes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to save it as unconfirmed, that load it via email and pass it to the send function:

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('newsletter_subscription_confirm_email_template');
            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
            $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
            $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber');
            if (!$subscriber->getId()
                || $subscriber->getStatus() == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED
                || $subscriber->getStatus() == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                // set subsc status to unconfirmed
                $subscriber->setStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED);
                $subscriber->setSubscriberEmail($email);
                $subscriber->setSubscriberConfirmCode($subscriber->RandomSequence());
                $subscriber->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                $subscriber->setCustomerId($order->getData('customer_id'));

                try {
                    $subscriber->save();
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
            try {
                $subscriber = $subscriber->loadByEmail($email);
                $emailTemplate->send($email, $order->getData('customer_firstname')." ".$order->getData('customer_lastname'), array('subscriber' => $subscriber));
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('customer')->__('An email was sent with a confirmation url'));
                $this->redirectSubscribeSuccess();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at default Magento confirmation email send function `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::sendConfirmationRequestEmail` You will see that they have used `$this`, object of `newsletter/subscriber` model to pass as `subscriber` in it.

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this)
);
```

You need to pass object of `newsletter/subscriber` to your custom email send function to make `{{var subscriber.getConfirmationLink()}}` work.
In your code you have passed blank `array()`
You can simply use

```
$newsletterObject = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber');
$emailTemplate->send($email, $order->getData('customer_firstname')." ".$order->getData('customer_lastname'), array('subscriber'=>$newsletterObject));
```

You may need to load current subscriber in `$newsletterObject`.

Comment: ok, Its a start, I get in the email the confirm url, which looks like: `baseurl/newsletter/subscriber/confirm/`. But when i clicked on it i don;t get subscribe and i am redirected to the home page.

Comment: The `id` and the `code` is missing :|

Comment: Yes, and to make it work, you first need to subscribe the email address. Please review `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::subscribe` function. Once you have added the subscriber email, you can pass object of that subscriber in your mail. You will notice that Confirmation email send function is there in the code. :)

Comment: please check my update. i got now the code , but the id is still missing . What did I do wrong ? thx

Comment: I need to add the subscriber->setId(''what here? ')  ?

Comment: Actually I needed to save it as unconfirmed, then get the subsc again and pass it to the send function